# How we can conclude that $p\nmid \sum_{x\in H}|x^G|$ in a group with some elements of order $2p$?

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that has some elements of order $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Let $H$ be the set of all elements of order $2p$ in $G$. We can show $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation. So $H$ cut to partition by orbits of this action. Hence $H=\bigcup_{x\in H}x^G$, where these conjugacy classes are distinct. It follows that $|H|=\sum_{x\in H}|x^G|$. How we can conclude that $p\nmid(\sum_{x\in H}|x^G|)$?

Comment: $p=1$ is a counterexample to this.

Comment: @MattSamuel maybe $p$ should be odd prime?

Comment: @Jihad that would make more sense, but it wasn't specified.

Comment: yes $p$ is odd prime.

Comment: There are other issues though. $|H|\neq \sum_{x\in H}{|x^G|}$ unless every element is the only element in its orbit. If we modify it so the equality does hold by summing over one element in each orbit, why not just just phrase the question as "prove that $p\nmid |H|$?" Or should it be $p\nmid \sum_{X\in H^G}{|X|^2}$, which is what the sum is really equal to?

Comment: This is very similar to a question  (from user mita) I answered on Mathoverflow today. The answer to this question is almost exactly the same. The number of elements of order $2p$ in $G$ is coprime to $p$ if and only if the number of involutions in $C_{G}(P)$ is coprime to $p,$ where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ ( at least when $p$ divides $|G|$ and is odd).

Comment: And of course you have to sum the size of the distinct orbits.

Comment: why you said that $|H|\neq\sum_{x\in H}|x^G|$ unless every element is the only element in its orbit? please explain more it. you want to say it is impossible that $H$ to be union of some orbits, which has more than one element?

Comment: $\sum_{x\in H}{|x^G|}$ is a sum over all elements of $H$ of the size of the orbit the element is in. For example, if there were only one orbit and the orbit had size $n$, then you would be adding a string of $n$ $n$'s, obtaining $n^2$. $|H|$ is equal to the sum over all orbits of the size of the orbit, not the sum over all elements.

Comment: yes, I was written that conjugacy classes are distinct. another question if the  conjugacy class sizes are same?